# How to display item from database as a label text in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am trying to show some text that i retrieved from the database and wanted to show them as a label or just show up on a page. I am having trouble displaying this text and here is what i have:

controller:

```
public ActionResult _StudentName(int id)
    {
        id = 12;
        var model = new StudentNameModel();
        using (var db = new School())
        {
            var result = from s in db.Students
                         where s.ID == id
                         select s.StudentName;
            model.StudentName = result.ToString();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

My Model:

```
public class StudentNameModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Student Name")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
    @model Adams.Models.StudentNameModel
     <fieldset>
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StudentName)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StudentName)
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Do you want the value as a read only label or as the inital value in a textbox that the user can edit?

Comment: @glosrob i just wanted to have it as a read only label - but i will also be using the idea of a textbos for the user to edit on a different feature so it would be great to have both ways.

Comment: Put a break point in your Action method `_StudentName` and try debugging and check whether result has any value or not

Comment: @Karthik I did and when i debug it is not even getting to the Action method. I am lost to what is wrong or what i might be missing.

Comment: Do you have `[HttpPost]` on your controllers action, please check ? Also your ControllerAction is prepended with `_`. Is your view name is `_StudentName.cshtml` ? If not please your controllers action to `StudentName` in your controllers action to get it hit

Comment: @Karthik my view is _StudentName.cshtml and my controller is _StudentName(int id) and i added [HttpPost] before `public ActionResult _StudentName(int id)` I am still getting nothing to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems you just need

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StudentName)
```

instead of

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StudentName)
```

by the way, change your query to something like

```
var studentName = (from s in from s in db.Students
                         where s.ID == id
                         select s.StudentName)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
if (student != null)
   model.StudentName = studentName;
```

Comment: Tried this but nothing was displayed. Does that mean that it didn't pull anything back from the database to display?

Comment: @072et seems so, yes. You had nothing with TextBoxFor, did you ?

Comment: i tried the TextBoxFor and didn't get anything to display. I am sure that i have an item to return from the database cuz i tested the sql query - is there something wrong in my control that i am not seeing?

Comment: @072et did you try the edited version of your query ? or not ?

Comment: My query is working fine but i just feel like in my code it is not even getting to my controller to retrieve the name.

Comment: I feel confused to where i should place my breakpoint to test i placed it @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.studentName) but while debugging it didn't even get to my controller.

Comment: @072et No. Put it in your Action ! It goes to Action, and Action returns a view (so Action first, View second).

Comment: @072et and change your query, sql != linq

Comment: I meant to say sql in the sql server and yest i changed my linq to the edited. I will go ahead and try the break point in my action

Comment: i am not sure what i am doing wrong when i debug it is not even hitting my action. Is there something i am doing wrong in the whole process? Are there tutorials with the same concept that i want i could follow? Really want to know what's wrong.